# Dell Inspiron battery diode on indefinitely

Tags: laptop, battery, dell-inspiron, battery-life, charging

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577 with specs hardly IMHO important, but someone might be of other opinion, so let me start with all that non-sense:

- BIOS/UEFI: updated to 1.16.0, latest to date;
- CPU: Intel Core i7-7700HQ (2.8GHz, TurboBoost up to 3.8GHz, HyperThreading enabled);
- RAM: 32GB RAM DDR4 2400MHz dual-channel (I've replaced and sold the original stick);
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design 6GB GDDR5;
- SSD #1: (from factory) M.2 PCIe NVMe Toshiba 512GB - OS primary: Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon kernel 5.4.x;
- SSD #2: (replaced HDD) SATA Samsung 870 QVO 1TB - OS secondary: Windows 10 Pro 21H2;
- Display: 3840 x 2160 (UHD 4K) 15.6" IPS;
- Power source: original 180W power adapter:

  [image]

---

### Battery BIOS setting I have set ever since I own it:

> **Primarily AC Use**

### Problem condition:

99.9% I am connected to power outlet. This 1‰ of time is caused by various power outages as we live on a very small village.

And if I happen to be on battery power for up to an hour (with 10% backlight), then either the OS shuts down as a precaution or I myself poweroff.

### Problem description:

A few months ago, when power went back on, I noticed the LED indicating charging **being constantly on even after days online** where OS Linux/Win10 would report 99% and charging! 3 year warranty is over, so Dell told me to solve it on my own.

Ideally, I would like a solution, in which the battery would stop charging and do not much care how, the easiest method wins, I will post my own, but there may be better or worse, depending on the point of view.

Thank you!

---

Battery capacity after ~3.5 years of use (screenshot taken from Linux):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaving the computer plugged in and charging to 100% which (in the years you have been doing this) will damage and weaken the battery.

See if your computer has Charging Threshold to hold the charge level to 80%.

This is the widely accepted to allow always plugged in without damaging the battery.

Many laptops have this function and I have it on my Lenovo X1, it is always plugged in, and battery health is fine.

This is the best way to manage your battery.

---

Image from Dell Power Manager (Windows users only):

[image]

---

Image from BIOS (generic method):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My own solution involves Dell Power Manager installed in Win10, hence implies Windows installed.

1. Launch Dell Power Manager;
2. Click on the big blue button "Settings";
3. Now choose **ExpressCharge™**, or if not available with your model, then I believe "Standard" would do the trick too (untested);
4. Click OK to save settings and wait for an hour or two;
5. Make sure to switch back to "Primarily AC Use" once the diode finally stops and OS reports 100% full battery.

---

Images for the words:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]